# CSS not applied during fullscreen Edge/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing `videojs` zoom plugin. Zooming is done with `transform: scale()` css property.
Initially I was testing on Firefox and everything works fine, however I've tried on Chrome and Edge and scale is not applied.

This doesn't work.

```
document.fullscreenElement.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
     .setAttribute('style', `transform: scale(3);  
     -webkit-transform: scale(3); 
     -ms-transform: scale(3)`);
```

But this does work fine on all browsers.

```
document.fullscreenElement.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
    .setAttribute('style', 
    `transform: rotate(90deg)`);
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The problem seems to be the hardware acceleration. Disabled on both Edge/Chrome and everything works fine. Not sure how to fix that without forcing clients to disable it.

Comment: Your style lacks the prefixless form of the property.

Comment: _“Not sure how to fix that without forcing clients to disable it.”_ - you could try and set the actual width and height of the video element instead – it has “scaling” already built-in, after all – and then clip it to only show a portion; maybe that works while HW acceleration is on?

Comment: @CBroe doesn't seem to take effect